# Swapping parts of a string using sed and regular expressions

Tags: regex

The following is a sample of a file I'm editing in vim

```
cutAct = new QAction( tr( "Cut" ) );
cutAct->setShortcut( QKeySequence::Cut );
cutAct->setStatusTip( tr( "Cut the current selection" ) );
connect( cutAct, SIGNAL( triggered() ), this, SLOT( cut() ) );
```

I'm trying to use sed from vim's command pane to convert all instances of `cutAct` to `actionCut`, with the intention being to test my expression before using it to carry out similar conversions on other elements of my code that have a `<someString>Act` name, so that they all instead follow a `action<SomeString>` naming convention. So basically:

1. Start with cutAct
2. Cut it in half before the 'Act' part, so it is cut and Act
3. Upper-case the 'c' in cut so I have 'Cut' and 'Act'
4. Drop the 'Act' and replace it with 'action' prepended to the front of 'Cut'.

This is an example of what I'm after

```
actionCut = new QAction( tr( "Cut" ) );
actionCut->setShortcut( QKeySequence::Cut );
actionCut->setStatusTip( tr( "Cut the current selection" ) );
connect( actionCut, SIGNAL( triggered() ), this, SLOT( cut() ) )
```

and I'm trying to use the following command to do it

```
s_[a-z]\(.*\)Act_action\u\1_g
```

but what I'm getting out is this

```
actionUtAct = new Qion( tr( "Cu&t" ), this );
actionUt->setShortcut( QKeySequence::Cut );
actionUt->setStatusTip( tr( "Cut the current selection" ) );
actionOnnect( cut, SIGNAL( triggered() ), diaryEditor, SLOT( cut() ) );
```

This is my first attempt at any serious use of regular expressions, and I would have believed that my expression would have returned every string starting with a lower case alpha character and anding in 'Act' before removing the Act from the end, making the first character upper-case and prepending 'action' to the front, but that clearly isn't what's happening.

Can someone please tell me how to modify my expression to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: It's difficult to **quickly** see what your problem is - I would suggest being much more explict about what the behaviour you want is, and what the behaviour you are seeing is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:

c**utAct = new QAct**ion( tr( "Cut" ) );

group 1 in the regular expression matches the part in italic. The initial `[a-z]` is outside the parentheses, and regular expressions are greedy, so `.*` followed by `Act` will match the *last* "Act" in the string, not the first.

Try this: `s_\([a-z]\w*\)Act_action\u\1_g`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
s_\([a-z]\w*\)Act_action\u\1_g
```

It produces the following result:

```
actionCut = new QAction( tr( "Cut" ) );
actionCut->setShortcut( QKeySequence::Cut );
actionCut->setStatusTip( tr( "Cut the current selection" ) );
connect( actionCut, SIGNAL( triggered() ), this, SLOT( cut() ) );
```

Comment: That looks like it didn't change anything?

Comment: @tripleee, you must have commented on the first version. I pasted wrong output, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` is greedy, i.e. it will match the longest possible string; in other words, you are replacing up to the *last* occurrence of "Act", not the first.

As far as I can see, the easiest way from A to B is `s_cutAct_actionCut_g`.

**Edit:** Here's a more general attempt at doing what you describe:

```
s_\([a-z]+\)Act_Action\u\1_g
```

In other words, for any lowercase string adjacent to Act, prepend Action, uppercase, and remove the Act suffix.